# Packages for NER in R

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to download openNLPmodels.en package in R for Named Entity Recognition but failed to download it successfully. Please suggest any other package in R for NER other than the above.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try to install it ?

Comment: I tried to download openNLPmodels.en package but failed so I want to try some other package in R for NER.

Comment: Just to check what you mean by "download", package `openNLPmodels.en` was removed from the CRAN repository so `install.packages` don't work

Comment: I tried with  "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/" but no luck, tried all alternatives too. so now want to download other package for NER in R

Comment: What is the error message ? Strange it doesn't work for all. For text mining I would use `tm` package, i don't know if it does what you want

Answer (score 2):

Though not on CRAN yet, I find `entity` package on GitHub useful for me. FYI: https://github.com/trinker/entity

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do Named Entity Recognition with custom labels, you can use package crfsuite. https://cran.r-project.org/web//packages/crfsuite/index.html